# String concatenation maintaining destination length

Tags: c, string, sockets, server, concatenation

I have a basic server-client program that I'm writing in C and I am stuck with an issue regarding strings and concatenation.
Basically I have some strings (in the example below just 2) that I have to put into a buffer which size is determined by:

```
  total # of registered people * 33
```

Both the strings in the example have a length which is much less than the length of the buffer. I want to obtain something like this after the concatenation:

```
            [0]            [32]
people_list=Mark           Amy\0;
```

where Mark(which is inserted secondly) is right at the start of the buffer (people_list) and Amy is 32 characters away from the start of Mark (I hope I've made myself clear).

This is because the client code was given to me and I cannot modify it. The client code takes the buffer and reads the first element, then jumps of 32 chars and reads again. 
The output I get from the printf of the client is this:

```
connected to server
Registered people:
 Mark
```

while I'd like this:

```
connected to server
Registered people:
 Mark
 Amy
```

The communication is implemented through sockets, which I have already checked, but if you wish to suggest some changes I would appreciate that.

Server code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define LENGTH 32

struct person {
    char name[LENGTH+1];
    struct person *next;
    struct person *prev;

};
struct person *p_head = NULL;

void addPerson(char* name_p){
    struct person *new = (struct person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    strcpy(new->name, name_p);
    new->name[LENGTH]='\0';
    new->next=p_head;
    new->prev=NULL;
    p_head=new;

}

int main(){

    int fd_ser;
    int fd_c;
    int N=100;
    char buf[N];
    int times=0;
    char* path="tmp/sock";

    struct sockaddr_un sa;

    unlink(path);
    sa.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(sa.sun_path,(char*) path, sizeof(sa.sun_path));

    if((fd_ser=socket(AF_UNIX,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0){   //socket
        perror((const char*) (size_t) errno);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if ( bind(fd_ser,(struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa))<0){
        perror("bind\n");
    }

    listen(fd_ser,10);  //listen


    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int addr_size= sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);

    fd_c=0;
    while( (fd_c=accept(fd_ser,(struct sockaddr*) &addr, (socklen_t*)&addr_size))<0){
        printf("waiting for connections...\n");
        sleep(2);
    }


    //initialize list of people
    char* Amy="Amy";
    char* Mark="Mark";

    addPerson(Amy);
    addPerson(Mark);

    //now concat the name strings in a buffer to be sent to the client

    char* people_list;
    unsigned int list_len;
    int value;

    struct person* ptr=(struct person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    ptr=p_head;
    int offset=0;
    int i=0;

    while(ptr!=NULL){
        i++;
        people_list=realloc(people_list,i*LENGTH); //every single name has to be LENGTH characters
        strcpy(&people_list[offset],ptr->name);
        ptr=ptr->next;
        offset=offset+LENGTH;
    }
    people_list[i*LENGTH]='\0';
    list_len=(i*LENGTH)+1;

    value=write(fd_c, &(list_len), sizeof(unsigned int));
    if(value==-1){
        perror("write length");
        return -1;
    }

    int toWrite=list_len;
    char *toRead=people_list;
    while(toWrite>0){
        value=write(fd_c, toRead, toWrite);
        if(value==-1){
            perror("write data");
            return -1;
        }
        toWrite=toWrite-value;
        toRead=toRead+value;
        if(toRead<=people_list + list_len) break;
    }

    close(fd_c);
    close(fd_ser);

    return 0;
}
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 2048
#define LENGTH 32

int main(){

    int fd_cli;
    char* path="tmp/sock";
    struct sockaddr_un sa;
    sa.sun_family=AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(sa.sun_path,(char*) path, sizeof(sa.sun_path));

    if( (fd_cli = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0))==-1){
        perror((const char*) (size_t) errno);
        return -1;
    }

    while( (connect(fd_cli,(struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un))) == -1 ) {
        if ( errno == ENOENT ) { sleep(1); }
        else perror("connect:");
        errno=0;
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("connected to server\n");

    int value;

    unsigned int len_data;

    value=read(fd_cli,&(len_data),sizeof(unsigned int));
    if(value==-1){
        perror("read length");
        return -1;
    }
    char* buffer=malloc(len_data*sizeof(char));

    int toRead=len_data;
    char *toWrite=buffer;
    while(toRead>0){
        value=read(fd_cli, toWrite, toRead);
        if(value==-1){
            perror("read buffer");
            return -1;
        }
        toRead=toRead-value;
        toWrite=toWrite+value;
        if(toWrite<=buffer + len_data) break;
    }


    int people_n = len_data / (LENGTH+1);
    assert(people_n > 0); //proceeds only if there is at least one person registered

    printf("Registered people:\n");

    for(int i=0,p=0;i<people_n; ++i, p+=(LENGTH+1)) {
        printf(" %s\n", &buffer[p]);
    }

    close(fd_cli);

    return 0;

}
```

I really hope I've explained the problem clearly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might want to read the client code carefully again, particularly the treatment of `LENGTH`.

Comment: `struct person* ptr=(struct person*) malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    ptr=p_head;
` you are leaking memory here.

Comment: @EOF Right! I wasn't considering that the client jumps of LENGTH+1 characters while I wasn't considering that in the server and now I fixed it. How blind I've been! Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @wildplasser right thank you, I'll fix it!

Answer (score 0):

It's printing only the first user (Mark) because of this line:

```
int people_n = len_data / (LENGTH+1);
```

In this example, `len_data = 65`, `LENGTH = 32`. So when you are adding 1 to `LENGTH`, it will return 1 (`65/33 = 1.96 => you get 1`). Then it only prints the first user.

Consider using `Valgrind`. It will help you checking the use of the memory.